# Stored HTML/PHP string in database won't evaluate when retrieved and echoed

Tags: php, html

This is the HTML/PHP before being stored in the database:`<li><a href="<?= dots('duo/'); ?>"><?= $item->item['Manufacturer']; ?></a> <span class="divider">|</span></li>`

This is the HTML/PHP after being stored in the database:

```
&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;&amp;lt;?= dots(&#39;duo/&#39;); ?&amp;gt;&quot;&gt;&amp;lt;?= $item-&amp;gt;item[&#39;Manufacturer&#39;]; ?&amp;gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;span class=&quot;divider&quot;&gt;|&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
```

I assign this result to a variable:

```
$crumbles = $details['Crumbs'];
```

I echo the result like so:

```
<?php echo html_entity_decode($crumbles); ?>
```

But it returns this when I view source. It's not evaluating any of the PHP in the string.

```
<li><a href="&lt;?= dots('duo/'); ?&gt;">&lt;?= $item-&gt;item['Manufacturer']; ?&gt;</a> <span class="divider">|</span></li>
```

It shows in the browser as `<?= $item->item['Manufacturer']; ?> |`

How can I get it to evaluate the PHP as well as display the html correctly?

EDIT: Here is the code that handles the input into the DB. It serializes the form data (url, crumbs, meta info, etc) and adds it to an ajax queue.

```
$("form#seo_add").submit(function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    var data            = $(this).serializeArray(),
        $commitBtn      = $(this).find("button"),
        form_incomplete = false,
        queueData       = ['seo_add', data];
```

When fired, the queue controller runs `$this->seo->add($seo_add, $user);`
Which is modeled like this:

```
function add($data = null, $username = null) {
    if (!is_array($data) || is_null($username)) die("Expecting new pageinfo");

    //if a single item is being inserted, add it to a parent array so iteration works
    if (!is_array($data[0]))
    {
        $data = array($data);
    }

    foreach ($data as $key => $page)
    {
        if (isset($page['section'])) unset($page['section']);
        if (isset($page['action'])) unset($page['action']);

        $add = $this->db->insert('pageinfo', $page);


        $page = array_merge(array('id'=>$this->db->insert_id()), $page);

        $last_queries[$key]['type'] = 'seo_add';
        $last_queries[$key]['html'] = "New page: <b>" . $page['page'] . "</b>";
        $last_queries[$key]['data'] = $page;
    }

    if ($this->db->_error_message())
        $this->db_error('Unable to insert page');

    return log_changes($last_queries, $username, $this->site);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share with us the code that is inserting the content into the database? It seems likely that your problem will be more correctly solved at the point of insert as opposed to the point of retrieving it.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen I added the code you mentioned. Is there a better way I could solve this? I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP tags are being double encoded at your PHP tags `&amp;lt;` so you can run `html_entity_decode` over it twice.

Even if your php tags were decoded they would never be interpreted by PHP since you're echoing them out straight away, the way around this is to run what your database returns through `eval` like so:

```
$crumbles = html_entity_decode(html_entity_decode($crumbles), ENT_QUOTES);
eval("?>{$crumbles}<?");
```

Comment: Be careful running anything through `eval()` unless you are 100% confident where the code is coming from. You can open yourself up to potential problems and security issues if not used with care.

Comment: OP wanted to run the code either way so I assumed he knew what the code contained

Comment: Works like a charm! Just out of curiosity, why does it work with ENT_QUOTES, but not without?

Comment: The code being eval'd is technically user input, but I'm the only user :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using placeholders.

```
$html = '<li><a href="[href]">[item]</a> <span class="divider">|</span></li>';
```

I suggest not saving the html encoded. This would do the trick for you I guess:

```
$html = str_replace(['href','item'],[dots('duo/'),$crumbles],$html);
```

Probably you've to encode the $crumbles or dots('duo/') if that is user input.